# Regex: Negating entire word instead of 1 character

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

If I do `[^>]` it negates characters that look like `>`.

How do I negate an entire word?

I.e. I want to do something like `[^people]` to ignore the entire word people?

**Edit #1:**

better example

```
   a bunch of other text before this <property datatype = ""system.string"" description=""the sql command to be executed."" name=""sqlcommand""UITypeEditor="">select col_1, col_2, from dbo.table</property> a bunch of other text after this
```

Right now, it only returns this:

```
<property datatype = ""system.string"" description=""the sql command to be executed."" name=""sqlcommand
```

But I want it to return this:

```
<property datatype = ""system.string"" description=""the sql command to be executed."" name=""sqlcommand""UITypeEditor="">select col_1, col_2, from dbo.table</property>
```

Comment: Use negative lookahead: `(?!people)`

Comment: Or negative lookbehind `(?<!people)`

Comment: [Lookaround tutorial](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: I added a more realistic example

Comment: *"Right now, it only returns"*: ... what does?

Comment: [^people] is the regex I was using

Comment: If that is the regex you were using, there is no way it would return what you say it returns. BTW: regexes don't return anything; python code does. Could you specify which code you are using, with the exact input and output?

Comment: Why don't you give `<property\s[^>]*>.*?</property\s*>` a try.

Comment: It also looks like you're parsing some kind of markup language, either XML or HTML. Have you considered using `BeautifulSoup` instead? Much, MUCH, *MUCH* easier.

Comment: Just based off your example, the following regex code would match your desired string (understood to be everything between a) '<property datatype' and b) '</property>'): 

r'(?<=\s)(<property datatype)(.*)(</property>)'

see: https://regex101.com/r/n9LHlt/1

Answer (score 3):

You can't negate a word using character class (`[]`), you need to look at **zero-width lookarounds**:

---

First, **lookaheads**:

To make sure `people` does not *immediately* follow the current token:

```
(?!people)
```

To make sure `people` does not follow the current token in any place afterwards:

```
(?!.*people)
```

---

Now, **lookbehinds:**

To make sure `people` does not *immediately* precede the current token:

```
(?<!people)
```

Python's `re` module does not support variable length lookbehind, so the following to make sure `people` does not come in any place before the current token position, does not work for `re`:

```
(?<!.*people)
```

but works for third-party `regex` module.

---

Here all the patterns are zero-width i.e. they don't consume characters in matching, just implement the logic.

Comment: I added a more realistic example

Comment: @LunchBox I don't get it. Whats your desired output from that example?

Comment: I added more details to my post, hope that makes sense.

Comment: @LunchBox I've seen your details and that does not make sense. You need to add what you want as output.

Comment: Clarified some more

Comment: @LunchBox So you want to match everything? Thats just `.*`

Comment: Edited my post again

Comment: @LunchBox Could you please take some time to add a complete example input, your conditions, and your desired output?

Comment: Your whole answer is about a look ahead/behind assertion and nothing else. Really, assertions don't cause you to _skip_ words. It's ridiculous.

Comment: I've never used  look aheads/behind assertions before. This is a new concept to me.  I was able to do everything I needed in the past without them so I never bothered learning them. Time to learn.

Comment: Heemayl: will do tonight

Comment: @LunchBox Great.